# difference between property accessor

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between accessing a property from the class through `$this` or through `new` operator or through scope resolution operator in PHP?

`$this->` vs `->` vs `::` in PHP

Comment: Welcome to the department of redundancy department.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961456/difference-double-colon-and-arrow-operators-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->` can be used from inside a class when referencing itself.

`$object->` is used from outside the class when referencing a specific object.

`$class_name::` is used when referencing a static property or method of a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

The differen between

```
$object->property;
Class::property;
```

is, that the first one access a object property, whereas the second one access a (`static`) class property. I really dont know, what you mean by "through new operator", because via `new` no property is accessable in any way, because `new` just creates a new object instance of a class. However, `$this->property` is exactly the same, as the first example above, but `$this` is only valid inside an object method  and always references the object itself.