# Class question - Beginner help

Tags: php, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and -> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and)

This a continuation from my previous question - however I think its unique enough to warrant a new question.

What is the difference between:

```
Message::listMessages();
```

and

```
$message->listMessages();
```

I'm creating a mini-cms and I want a system that displays errors in a uniform fashion.

Cheers,
Keiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Static methods come handy when we want to share
information between objects of a class, or want to represent something
that's related to the class itself, not any particular object.**

The difference between the two is in the way they are invoked.
For example, `Message::listmessages()` is a static method and can be called like this:

```
$messages = Message::listmessages($args);
```

You do not need to first make an object of class Message, in order to use the above. Also, note that this should be used when you want to return a result on definite pre-configured variables, and is not based on properties of class Message

However, `$message->listmessages()` is an instance method and can be called like this:

```
$message = new Message();
$messages->$args = $args
$messages= $message->listmessages();
```

This is used for generic occassions when you want to call a function on runtime properties of class Message.

Answer (score 1):

As i understood your question,

we are using this way  `Message::listMessages();`  in `C` and `C++`

but right syntax we are using in `PHP` is `$message->listMessages();`

Thanks.

Comment: PHP supports both the `::` and `->` operators but they mean different things. See the other answers for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your class `Message` is defined like this:

```
class Message {
  //...
  static function listMessages() {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

They are same, they both call the static method `listMessages` from `Message`, however, `$message->listMessages()` requires less lookup.

According to a test, you cannot declare two methods with same names, one static and one member:

```
$ php5-cgi 
<?php
class A { static function f() { }
          function f() { } }
?>
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare A::f() in - on line 2
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5
Content-type: text/html
```

Comment: PHP allows you to define just one non-static method and call it statically or non-statically. Like this: `class A { function f() {} } A::f(); $a = new A(); $a->f();`. Not that I would recommend ever doing such nonsense, but PHP does allow it.

Answer (score 1):

This is calling a static method, i.e. a method on a *class*:

```
Message::listMessages();
```

This is calling an instance method, i.e. a method on an *object* (aka instance of a class):

```
$message->listMessages();
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Message::listMessages() is a static function so it should be used when listMessages() is disregarding you're object propretyes , ie. return some class constants or variables or ... anything you like . ( static means it should have the same output for all instances of Message class )

$message->listMessages() may use you're object propretyes so output could be different for two different objects of the same Message class with different propretyes ( say $messages and $messages1 ) .

Answer (score 0):

The class `Message` is calling its own method without an object means the method is static no object have rights to call this method only class can call.

```
Message::listMessages();
```

The object of class `Message` is calling the public method

```
$message->listMessages();
```