# PHP difference in accessing class methods

Tags: php, class, methods

What's the difference between `$foo->bar()` and `$foo::bar()`?

Comment: Read more about static @ http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and -> ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and)

Comment: *(related)* [Reference: What does Symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$foo::bar()` is a call of the static method `bar()`, that means the object `$foo` was not instanciated by the `__construct()` method.

When calling `$foo->bar()`, the object `$foo` has to be instanciated before! Example:

```
$foo = new Foo; // internally the method __constuct() is called in the Foo class!
echo $foo->bar();
```

Often you don't call a static method on a existing object like in you example (`$foo`), you can call it directly on the class Foo:

```
 Foo::bar();
```

Comment: What should "that means the object $foo was not instanciated by the __construct() method." mean? Its not possible to instanciate objects without calling `__construct()` :?

Comment: At @KingCrunch, it is possible to instanciate a object without (auto) calling __construct(), when there is no __construct method defined. But it would not make that much sense, in such a case you would choose to call all other methods in the static way.

Answer (score 0):

With the first one

```
$foo->bar();
```

you call (object) methods, whereas with

```
Foo::bar();
```

you call class (static) methods.

Its possible to call class methods on objects. That is, what your second example does. So this

```
$foo = new Foo;
$foo::bar();
```

is identical to

```
Foo::bar();
```

or even

```
$classname = get_class($foo);
$classname::bar();
```

Update:
Missed something
`$foo` can also just be a string with a classname.

```
$foo = 'Baz';
$foo::bar(); // Baz::bar();
```

Comment: -1: I'm very sorry to downvote, but calling static method on objects causes PHP to spit out notices, arguably meaning the code isn't entirely correct. In my humble opinion, this is a practice which many people unfortunately took up for granted.

Comment: I said its possible, not that is a good idea. Then, it was exactly, what the questioner wants to know. And it will not throw a notice anymore with PHP5.3 and up. However, I agree, thats not very good practice. (OK, maybe I forgot, that `$foo` can also be a string ^^)