# PHP: Difference between -> and ::

Tags: php, function, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and ->?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and)

In PHP, what is the main difference of while calling a function() inside a class with arrow `->` and Scope Resolution Operator `::` ?

For more clearance, the difference between:

```
$name = $foo->getName();
$name = $foo::getName();
```

What is the main profit of Scope Resolution Operator `::` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$name = $foo->getName();
```

This will invoke a member or static function of the object `$foo`, while

```
$name = $foo::getName();
```

will invoke a static function of the class of `$foo`. The 'profit', if you wanna call it that, of using `::` is being able to access static members of a class without the need for an object instance of such class. That is,

```
$name = ClassOfFoo::getName();
```

Comment: `::` can accessible to `static` members of class??? woah! Enough profit so! :D Thanks buddy, K-ballo

Comment: If `::` can access to the `static` member, so what is the beauty of `static`?? I think this is just an un-structured way in PHP :(

Comment: You seem to be confusing `static` with something else, in all languages there are ways to access static (public) members of a class.

Comment: much more detailed answer regarding this topic can be found here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027307/4126723

Answer (score 9):

- -> is called to access a method of an instance (or a variable of an instanciated object)
- :: is used to access static functions of an uninstanced object

Answer (score 1):

They are for different function types. `->` is always used on an object for static and non-static methods (though I don't think it's good practice use `->` for static methods). `::` is only used for static methods and can be used on objects (as of PHP 5.3) **and more importantly classes**.

```
<?php

class aClass {
    static function aStaticMethod() {}
    function aNormalMethod() {}
}

$obj = new aClass();
$obj->aNormalMethod(); //allowed
$obj->aStaticMethod(); //allowed
$obj::aStaticMethod(); //allowed as of PHP 5.3
$class_name = get_class( $obj );
$class_name::aStaticMethod(); //long hand for $obj::aStaticMethod()
aClass::aStaticMethod(); //allowed
//aClass::aNormalMethod(); //not allowed
//aClass->aStaticMethod(); //not allowed
//aClass->aNormalMethod(); //not allowed
```

Comment: `$obj->aStaticMethod(); //allowed` Allowed???? Dude, i'm getting confusing about `->`. Are you sure it `->` is allowed for that?

Comment: Try running the script. It works but it's not really best practice.