# Yii2: echo variable twice gives wrong result

Tags: php, yii2

Well I have a function `getDaysTotal` in my model say estimate.php.

If in my view.php if I use

```
echo $model->DaysTotal;
```

I get the value 3. But if I do it again

```
echo $model->DaysTotal;
```

Now I get 1. Any idea, why I am getting it like this. 
This is happening for any function in estimate.php. 
If I am using it for second time the result is weird.

Am I doing anything wrong here? How can I correct this?
Thanks.

Here is the code for `getTotalDays` function:

```
public function getDaysTotal() {
               $this->discharge_date = strtotime($this->discharge_date);
               $this->admission_date = strtotime($this->admission_date);

               $datediff = ($this->discharge_date - $this->admission_date);

               $fraction_days = ($datediff/(60*60*24));

               if ($fraction_days < 1){
                          return 1;

               }elseif(($datediff)%(60*60*24) < 10800){
                 $option2 = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
                 return $option2;
               }elseif(($datediff%86400) > 10800 && ($datediff%86400)<21600) {
                  $option3 = ceil($datediff/(60*60*24)*2)/2;
                  return $option3;
               }elseif (($datediff%86400) >21600){
                   $option4= ceil($datediff/86400);
                   return $option4;
               }
```

Comment: post the code of your function geDaysTotal

Comment: Hi @IsabelHM - question update with the function code.

Comment: you also use `admision_date` / `discharge_date` getters. May be one of them have a side effect.

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong) You just change it both in first two lines... :)

Comment: Use internal variables for storing `strtotime` results...

Comment: Hi @vp_arth - You hit the nail on the head. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getter changes your object:

```
public function getDaysTotal() {
           $this->discharge_date = strtotime($this->discharge_date);
           $this->admission_date = strtotime($this->admission_date);
```

You should not to do it. On next call `strtotime(int)` returns false for both lines.

Try followed:

```
public function getDaysTotal() {
           $discharge_date = strtotime($this->discharge_date);
           $admission_date = strtotime($this->admission_date);
           $datediff = ($discharge_date - $admission_date);
```

Used aux vars here, without any object state modifying.

Comment: Thank you so so much @vp_arth. Your suggestion resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny that you're getting anything because "echo $var"  might be a non-object.

```
    <?php
       $a = 6;
       echo $a -> b;
    ?>

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object.
```

IN PHP the right pointing arrow "->" is used to access the component parts of an object, in php it is similar to "::" or the humble "." in languages like java and the C family.

**Without more context** it is impossible to tell what exactly is happening in you're case but perhaps [this page  on the "->"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/whats-the-difference-between-double-colon-and-arrow-in-php) will be helpful for you.

If that dosn't give you what you need here is a [general PHP note card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: No for the first time I am getting the correct result. Only problem is when I am using it again, I am facing the problem.