# Understanding an article regarding scope resolution in PHP

Tags: php

I was looking for when and how scope resolution **::** is used. So I found out that it can be used for calling static variable/function and also for. But there seems to be more to it considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173511/12956279) in Stack Overflow.

My confusion is about the last two lines of code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173511/12956279):

```
/* This is more tricky
 * in the first case, a static call is made because $this is an
 * instance of A, so B::dyn() is a method of an incompatible class
 */
echo '$a->dyn():', "\n", $a->callDynamic(), "\n";

/* in this case, an instance call is made because $this is an
 * instance of B (despite the fact we are in a method of A), so
 * B::dyn() is a method of a compatible class (namely, it's the
 * same class as the object's)
 */
echo '$b->dyn():', "\n", $b->callDynamic(), "\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::` is called in static uses. This is meant for classes with static properties and methods where you call it **without** an instance.

```php
class A {
    public static function callMethod(): void {}
}

A::callMethod();
```

will call method `callMethod()` without having an instance.

```php
class A {
    public function callMethod(): void {}
}

$a = new A();
$a->callMethod();
```

will call `callMethod()` from instance `$a`.

Note, that static methods can **only** be called **without instance**.

## Additional explanation

From the answer you linked, a method is called *dynamically* even it was not defined. When you use the [magic caller method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), this is possible.

```php
class A {
    public function __call($name, $arg) {
        $args = implode(', ', $arg ?? []);
        echo "You called {$name} with ({$args})\n";
    }
}
```

So now you can call any method without an exception.

```php
$a = new A();
$a->hello('world');
```

> You called hello with (world)

Comment: weirdly, i can comment here but not to the post i gave link to. I understand the concept of static but my confusion is with the 2 lines of code I mentioned in my question.

Comment: `public function __call($name, $arguments) {}` is the **magic** of the second line. This is a [magic function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) will be called, when a method of an instance is called **which is not existing**. Name is the name of the method. You can use this trick for magic getters (__get) and setters (__set), but I do not recommend using that.

Comment: thanks. I think i understand now. I am accepting your answer but can you please also add your comments with your answer?